# Comb vs Braid (or any specific hairstyle.)

Tags: word-usage, usage

We usually have to braid our hair to school.

What sounds a better out of the two options below:

> Do you comb your hair on your own? (Like anything, can be a braid, a ponytail etc, nothing too fancy)
>
> Do you braid your hair on your own?

And if the hairstyle if fancy (not for school, of course)

> Do you style your hair on your own?

Answer (score 1):

This is a comb: [image: Comb]

To "comb one's hair" is specifically act of using one of these. It would be unusual to ask somebody if they do this, and this doesn't appear to be the question you intend.

Therefore, of the two options you've given, it would be better to say, "do you braid your hair on your own?".

That said, a native speaker would probably say:

> Do you braid your own hair?

Or more generally,

> Do you do your own hair?

Comment: You _comb_ your hair to smooth it or pull out tangles. It doesn't mean 'arrange it in a hairstyle' (unless you have short hair that just needs to be tidied with a comb).

Comment: +1 for *Do you **do** your own hair?* Which covers a lot of different possibilities (including cutting, washing, perming,..), but *context* usually makes it fairly obvious which *specific* aspect of "hair care" is being asked about.